# JBoss Drools Scala

Tags: scala, jboss, drools

I'm trying to implement a [sample](http://www.gettingcirrius.com/2010/12/using-jboss-rules-drools-in-scala.html) of integration between JBoss Drools framework and Scala and I've found an issue I cannot solve.
When I try to compile, the scala compiler just outputs an error saying that KnowledgeBuilderFactory is broken...
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it an exact error message?

Comment: scala: error while loading KnowledgeBuilderFactoryService, class file '/home/augusto/Development/lib/drools-distribution-6.0.1.Final/binaries/kie-internal-6.0.1.Final.jar(org/kie/internal/builder/KnowledgeBuilderFactoryService.class)' is broken
(class java.lang.NullPointerException/null)

Comment: It happens for class KnowledgeBuilderFactory too... I think its the same problem

Comment: It doesn't look like you're showing enough of the stack trace in your question. From what I have seen in similar examples, the missing class is declared to be 'not found' a couple of lines before the 'broken' error.

Comment: There's just a warning and its after the error saying com.sun.tools.xjc.Options not found

Comment: Post the entire stack trace. Don't ask us to guess the details.

Comment: Its a compilation error. This is the only output the IDE gives to me...

Comment: I agree with @Steve and Paul that pasting complete stack trace would help. Now we see which exact file is missing. If my last edit/suggestion does not help please provide Scala, Java and SBT versions you use.

Comment: If you had said in the first place that the first error reported was that `com.sun.tools.xjc.Options` was missing, it would have helped. That's the error. You don't have JAXB on the classpath.

Comment: Here what did to get this error: http://pastebin.com/2jDGCQHW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is caused by missing class/jar/dependency. You need to get all dependencies (jars) on to your classpath. If you are using the Eclipse zip project from that page you are not provided with these jars by default. Take a look at `.classpath` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
        <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
        <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.scala-ide.sdt.launching.SCALA_CONTAINER"/>
        <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.6"/>
        <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.USER_LIBRARY/Drools 5.1.1"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Users/claytonrl/Development/org.eclipse.jdt.core_3.5.2.v_981_R35x.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Users/claytonrl/Software/drools-5.1.1-bin/lib/antlr-2.7.6.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Users/claytonrl/Software/drools-5.1.1-bin/lib/antlr-runtime-3.1.3.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Users/claytonrl/Software/drools-5.1.1-bin/lib/mvel2-2.0.16.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Users/claytonrl/Software/drools-5.1.1-bin/lib/xstream-1.3.1.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

Most likely you don't have this directory `/Users/claytonrl/Software/` on your computer and all those drools jars in it. If so download those from maven repository and put them in `lib` directory.

As suggested [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/simple-build-tool/PJJDLqMWHzo) adding this `libraryDependencies += "com.sun.xml.bind" % "jaxb-xjc" % "2.2.4-1"` dependency to your SBT should help in this exact case.

Comment: I've downloaded and created the project on my own. I didn't use this one. I've tried with 6.0.1 version and 5.4 but the same error pops out. I'm sure I added all the jars from these distributions mannually

Comment: did you check that you've added all dependencies for your dependencies as well? If you are using any build tool like maven, SBT, etc it will usually get everything for you.

Comment: You can try seemingly complete jar package from here: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/drools/drools-all/2.0, or pick whichever version you need, also this looks even more appropriate candidate: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.kie/kie-api/6.0.1.Final. I don't know exactly what libs you need but notice "This artifact depends on ..." - you have to have those too, and so on recursively.

Comment: The best option would be to convert your project to SBT - easier and faster.

Comment: I prefer Gradle to SBT, but either way, you definitely need a build tool to grab all transitive dependencies as @AlekseyIzmailov says.

Comment: @ACDias Admittedly, I don't have any experience with scala, but the wording of that error message suggests to me that the jar file *is* there but that scala isn't happy with its contents. Is it possible that there is a (Java) compiler version conflict?

Comment: I've tried with SBT too and had no success. Based on what I read I think the problem is with the sacala compiler. It seems there are some scenarios that it cannot read the java library, but I'm not sure this is the problem here